# Spring WebFlux WebClient hangs and Mono.timeout doesn't catch it

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have rather simple Kotlin code which always blocks and never returns:

```
WebClient
        .create()
        .get()
        .uri("https://httpbin.org/status/200")
        .exchange()
        .flatMap {
            println("Status ${it.statusCode()}")
            it.bodyToMono(String::class.java)
        }
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5), Mono.just("fallback"))
        .map { println("Response $it") } // never runs
        .block()
```

- `httpbin` in this case returns no content (only headers), so is that so that `bodyToMono` waits forever for the content here? Is there solid way how to handle such case (reading Content-Length is not reliable)
- I set Mono.timeout with fallback value, why doesn't it cover that?

Comment: Could you provide more information about your project, Spring Boot version, Kotlin version? I've just created a Kotlin project on start.spring.io, copied that snippet into a test and it works fine. Also, note that you probably want to use `doOnNext` instead of the `map` operator in the last segment (otherwise, your pipeline is returning Unit).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've created example repo with build.gradle file which includes all the versions https://github.com/artemyarulin/spring-webflux-webclient-stuck-example

Comment: I've just tested this in my IDE with JDK8, JDK9, JDK10 and JDK11. It works fine.

Comment: Does it produce the second line in log? For me I see only `Status 200` message from `streamer.Test`, but I don't see `Response *` log message there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, httpbin.org does not return a response body, so the `bodyToMono` method will return the equivalent of `Mono.empty()`.

If you change the `map { println("Response $it") }` (which will never run, since wee don't get a body) into a `doOnSuccess { log.info("Response received") }`, the `"Response received"` message is printed.

This means that the `Mono` is not stuck, it just completed with an empty body.

Comment: Thank you. Important lesson for me, I though timeout + doOnError would cover all possible edge cases, but completely forgot about empty sequences

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. After reading the answer from Brain I think the real problem still can't be resolved. Actually we need to take action for response without body, e.g. reply with a Mono.just (just like Artem want to do after timeout). Now`timeout()` can't handle this case, but `doOnSuccess()` seems can't handle this case as well because it will be called for either having body or no body. In the `doOnSuccess()` we still can't know whether the clientReponse has a body or not then take different action.

And as Brian said before doOn** has side-effects is only for log usage.

Comment: I've ended up using .defaultIfEmpty("fallback"), can't you use that?

Comment: Thank you, it works around. Its little different with no body.